# How to load a new css file by not loading existing css file

Tags: css, spring

I am using spring, when i run my project in web common.css files and js files will load. Now, when i run project the existing css file should not load, new css file should load in runtime.For example, if i open my project in web then a.css file sholud load , if i open it from android b.css file should load.

In spring i used web interceptor class http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/spring-framework-2.5.3/src/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/WebContentInterceptor.java.shtml, in this class i am getting file paths from lookup path variable when i run my project . Here i tried to update file path but it is not working.please help me how can we do it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you would place the second css file after the first

Comment: Replace the old file with the new one or import the new one at the end of the old one using @import

Comment: Thanks for your help but i need existing css file should not load but new css file should load. is it possible? I have edited my question.please check it

Answer (score 0):

Add that css file which you want to override other after that file.
For example you you want to override 'a.css' to 'b.css' than

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="b.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a.css">
```

Here `a.css` will override `b.css`

Comment: Thanks for your help but i need existing css file should not load but new css file should load. I have edited my question.please check it.